# Get Google Page Rank

Tags: c#, pagerank

I want to get the page rank for any website. I have tried many approaches but they all work for only a small list: 5 to 10 pages.  And there are delays. After that, querying yields: `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden`. And I have learned that it is against Google's terms and conditions to use the Google Toolbar query to get bulk page ranks. I have seen people recomend `PageRankAJAX API` by Google, however it is no longer supported.
Can anyone help me with determine bulk page ranks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Google will have to limit how many page ranks you can query at once.

Google has so many pages ranked that if they allowed users to query for too many Page Ranks at the same time, there could be all kinds of problems.  Users could overwhelm Google's servers by requesting billions of ranks every second.  Users could... clone large portions of Google's service. There area a lot of bad possibilities if they don't limit that API.

With enough effort you may be able to increase the number of results you yield, but I am sure Google will work hard to keep people from accessing too many page ranks at one time.