# How to get website ranking by query in google

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC 4 project where I need to implement next future:

1. I have website url
2. Search string

I need based on this two options get web site ranking in google response, does anybody know how to do this using c# & asp.net mvc. I'm new in this circle of development.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182838/get-google-page-rank

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688825/checking-domain-page-rank-from-c-sharp

Comment: try this class http://snipplr.com/view/48906/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the complete source code [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/services/get-google-pagerank-programatically). Credit goes to [Jonathan Wood](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/UserProfile.aspx?id=92bafce6-89de-445c-a8ce-07b0f6f020ca) for complete code, I tested it and it is working as expected. You can combine your website url and its querystring into a string, then pass that string to the GetPAgeRank(string url) method. Alternatively you if you only want to website ran, then ignore querystring and send only website address like - http://www.stackoverflow.com

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public class GooglePageRank
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the PageRank of the given URL. Return values are 0 through 10 or
    /// -1 (N/A), which indicates there was an error or the URL is not in the
    /// Google index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">URL to test</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int GetPageRank(string url)
    {
        int rank = -1;

        try
        {
            // Form complete URL
            url = String.Format("http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr" +
                "?client=navclient-auto&features=Rank&ch={0}&q=info:{1}",
                ComputeHash(url), UrlEncode(url));

            // Download page
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string response = stream.ReadToEnd();

            // Parse page rank value
            string[] arr = response.Split(':');
            if (arr.Length == 3)
                rank = int.Parse(arr[2]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Do nothing but return -1;
        }
        return rank;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// URL-encodes the given URL. Handy when HttpUtility is not available
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">URL to encode</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string UrlEncode(string url)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in url)
        {
            if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
                builder.Append(c);
            else if (c == ' ')
                builder.Append('+');
            else if ("()*-_.!".IndexOf(c) >= 0)
                builder.Append(c);
            else
                builder.AppendFormat("%{0:X2}", (byte)c);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes a hash value required by Google
    /// </summary>
    private static string ComputeHash(string url)
    {
        UInt32 a, b;
        UInt32 c = 0xE6359A60;
        int k = 0;
        int len;

        // Modify URL
        url = string.Format("info:{0}", url);

        a = b = 0x9E3779B9;
        len = url.Length;

        while (len >= 12)
        {
            a += (UInt32)(url[k + 0] + (url[k + 1] << 8) + (url[k + 2] << 16) + (url[k + 3] << 24));
            b += (UInt32)(url[k + 4] + (url[k + 5] << 8) + (url[k + 6] << 16) + (url[k + 7] << 24));
            c += (UInt32)(url[k + 8] + (url[k + 9] << 8) + (url[k + 10] << 16) + (url[k + 11] << 24));
            Mix(ref a, ref b, ref c);
            k += 12;
            len -= 12;
        }

        c += (UInt32)url.Length;
        switch (len)
        {
            case 11:
                c += (UInt32)(url[k + 10] << 24);
                goto case 10;
            case 10:
                c += (UInt32)(url[k + 9] << 16);
                goto case 9;
            case 9:
                c += (UInt32)(url[k + 8] << 8);
                goto case 8;
            case 8:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 7] << 24);
                goto case 7;
            case 7:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 6] << 16);
                goto case 6;
            case 6:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 5] << 8);
                goto case 5;
            case 5:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 4]);
                goto case 4;
            case 4:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 3] << 24);
                goto case 3;
            case 3:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 2] << 16);
                goto case 2;
            case 2:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 1] << 8);
                goto case 1;
            case 1:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 0]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        Mix(ref a, ref b, ref c);
        return string.Format("6{0}", c);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ComputeHash() helper method
    /// </summary>
    private static void Mix(ref UInt32 a, ref UInt32 b, ref UInt32 c)
    {
        a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 13;
        b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 8;
        c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 13;
        a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 12;
        b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 16;
        c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 5;
        a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 3;
        b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 10;
        c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 15;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand in your example I have only rank of url, without any queries or phrases which analyze how this site match for this query?

Comment: And how can I combine url & query string?

Comment: you could use something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls

Comment: But where I must put my query string and how its looks like?

Comment: `Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.mysite.com");
            Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "home/index?p=123");` and then access it like `myUri.AbsoluteUri`, that will print - `http://www.mysite.com/home/index?p=123`

Comment: You're awesome, I don't know how to tell how I grateful for you.

Comment: But what I should to do if I know only websitename: http://www.mysite.com and query keywords: "my query string". Just simple split this into http://www.mysite.com/?p=my-query-string and send to google toolbar?

Comment: Its always -1 for me.

Comment: Google dropped the showing of PageRank several years ago (maybe 2016).  I think the question was to find the rank of the page, not the PageRank.  Other companies like Majestic, MOZ, and AHRefs have made up their own stats now to approximate PageRank.